# LibreOffice spell checking visual feedback

Tags: spell-checking, libreoffice, writer

While editing documents in LibreOffice Writer, spell check errors are pointed out using red or blue wavy underline according to the kind of error that has been recognized.

Is there a (simple) mean to customize this visual feedback in order to increase its visibility ?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the version of LibreOffice being used, the colors used when indicating a spelling or grammatical errors can be changed in the preferences under `LibreOffice -> Application Colors`.

For spell check the custom color that you would want to alter would be titled `AutoSpellcheck`.

[image: LibreOffice Application Colors window]

Comment: Nice catch, but this is limited to color. I was also looking for thickness.

Comment: oh that was totally unclear. Yah i think you'd have to do some extra shit, like modify the original codebase and rebuild it. Or. Idk. Probably some way to pick a hex code and have your pc monitor for it and apply an effect... Messy, but a possibility.